# Only two groups of order 10.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have shown a group of order 10 has a cyclic subgroup of order 5. But now I am stuck. Any hints?

Comment: No because I do not understand the answers on there

Comment: @Lin that doesn't stop it from being a duplicate question

Comment: Then what can I do to get a better answer which I understand?

Comment: I would comment on the answers there asking about the specifics that you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $D_{10}$ and $C_{10}$ are both groups of order $10$. You know that there is a subgroup of order $5$, so what does that tell you about the possible arrangements of the rest of the elements of the group? Consider assuming there is an element of order 10, and then try assuming there is no element of order 10. Each assumption should be enough to prove $G$ is one of the two groups above. You know there is a group of order 2 inside of $G$ as well, and $(2,5)=1$

Comment: By $C_5$ is meant the dihedral group here? (If so I think it is usually denoted by a $D$ with subscript.

Comment: I mean the cyclic group?

Comment: I need to show C_10 and D_10 are the only 2 groups of order 10

Comment: Yes. $D_10=Z/10Z$

Comment: But $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ is already the cyclic group of order $10$.

Comment: Wow yes I'm silly

Comment: What can I say about the group of order 2?